# How we set the margin top,left margin of UITextField and UILabel for ios

Tags: xcode, ios7

How we set the margin top,left margin of UITextField and UILabel for ios. I am using this code for custom header of a table view.I want to top margin 28px and left margin 335px.

```
     UILabel *sets = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 10, 130, 20)];
        sets.text = @"Sets";
        sets.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255 green:53.0/255.0 blue:55.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        ;
        [sets setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica neue Regular" size:6.0]];
        sets.tag = 3;
        [headerView addSubview:sets];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your frame to be `CGRectMake(335.0, 28.0, your_width, your_height)` and add the label as a subview of the header, just as your are now. Alternatively, you could create constraints.